# python says “no module named nest” when it is in the $PATH

Tags: python, shell, path, nest-simulator

`import nest` gives the 'no module named nest' error when it is in the `$PATH`, which means that there is a `/opt/nest/lib/python2.7/site-packages:` in my system `$PATH`. At this location there is a directory named `nest` and the structure inside the `nest` directory is looks like:

[image]

, where there is an `__init__.py` obviously. So why can't python find `nest`?

more information:

I am sure that I installed nest with python2.7, and run it with the same python2.7.

Comment: It should be in `$PYTHONPATH` I think

Comment: @AndreySobolev How to add? `echo $PYTHONPATH` returns nothing.

Comment: The Python module search path is not the same as the system PATH.  Run Python and do `import sys; print sys.path` and see what you have there.

Comment: @BrenBam I think you got the key. It's not there. How to add?

Comment: Look for site.py - that is generally the place where system-wide sys.path changes can be made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/install/index.html), there are several ways to install python packages:

1. using `distutils` - running `python setup.py install` installs the package to `site-packages` of your current distribution;
2. passing `--user` to `setup.py install` installs module to `~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` on Unix, and this directory in under normal conditions always included in `sys.path`;
3. passing `--home=$HOME` to `setup.py install` installs module under `$HOME` directory. This directory should be included to `sys.path` explicitly;
4. modifying python search path:

you can do either

```
   import sys
   sys.path.append('/opt/nest/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
```

in the beginning of your script; or your can add

```
PYTHONPATH=/opt/nest/lib/python2.7/site-packages
export PYTHONPATH
```

in the end of your `~/.bash_profile` file.

UPDATE:

Just tried to install `nest` and found that it comes in two flavours - 32bit (under `/opt/nest/lib`) and 64bit (under `/opt/nest/lib64`). You might have tried to use 32-bit python package with 64-bit python distribution. Try to change the string in `./zshrc` to 
`PYTHONPATH=/opt/nest/lib64/python2.7/site-packages` and see if it works. It works for me at least.

Comment: I tried to add it in my `./zshrc` file, and reboot my system. It doesn't work. Python still gives the error:-( Did I miss something?

Comment: What does `echo $PYTHONPATH` output?

Comment: /opt/nest/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Comment: And is it now in your `sys.path`?

Comment: Nope. I tried manually copy the files to a path in my `sys.path` and it works now. I still can't add it to `sys.path`.

Comment: There's no `lib64` in my `/opt/nest/`. Only `bin`, `lib` and `share` are there.

Answer (score 0):

To set relevant environment variables correctly, NEST installs have a config that you can just source

```
source <installpath>/bin/nest_vars.sh
```

That sets the `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH` correctly and points NEST to the right directories for dynamically loaded content (modules, help pages, …)